# Why doesn't icon show after ellipses inside a table row?

Tags: html, css

I have the following scenario:

```
<td><div> long text </div><div> <img src=""/><div></td>
```

I am able to see ellipses when the window size is small but the icon never shows with the ellipses.

When the window is maximized it should expand the text or display full text along with icon on right, immediately after text.

For example

A small window displayed like:

> Text text text text text text text text text text text text text...[ICON]
>
> text text text text text text text text text[ICON]

When Maximized - no ellipses

> Text text text text text text text text text text text text text text [ICON]
>
> text text text text text text text text text[ICON]

Comment: Can you post the CSS for your example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)